# ActiveRecord Validations allows spaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, validation, activerecord

I am validating a model using a regex:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  USER_REGEX = /[-\w]/i

  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 16 }, format: { with: USER_REGEX }
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true, format: { with: EMAIL_REGEX }
end
```

However, the :name-field is not correctly validated. If i go into ´rails console´ and create a new instance of the User class, i can set :name to a string containing spaces and .valid? still returns true. If I test the regex in irb, it does not match any spaces.

A demonstration:

```
$ rails c --sandbox
...
2.0.0-p451 :001 > u = User.new name: "hello world", email: "test@example.com"
2.0.0-p451 :002 > u.valid?
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'test@example.com' LIMIT 1
 => true
```

I am using Ruby 2.0.0-p451 on Linux, with rails 4.0.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expression isn't anchored, and has no quantifier. `/[-\w]/i` matches any string that has *any character* matching that regex.

The correct regex would be...

```
USER_REGEX = /\A[-\w]+\Z/i
```

That will match the beginning of the string (`\A`), followed by **one or more** instances of `[-\w]` (the `+` is the quantifier) and then the end of the string (`\Z`). The anchors are vital; they cause the regex to match either the entire string, or nothing.

Comment: Thank you! That really helped me out. It works now, although it seems like `\a` needs to be capitalized (`\A`).